# Spotlight: search any word using services without opening Finder

Tags: macos, finder, osx-mavericks, spotlight

I'm using Mavericks on a Mac. The "services" shortcuts allow me to highlight a word and search for this word in spotlight. This searches for the word in a new Finder window. Is it possible to highlight any word and search for this in spotlight in the drop down blue box in the top right corner of the screen (therefore without opening a Finder window)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might create a service like this with Automator:

[image]

However it would be easier to just press C, space and V while holding command.